# How to use QGIS from command line on Windows

Tags: qgis, windows, shell

I have QGIS running on a windows operating system.
I am willing to use QGIS from command line to follow this [procedure](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/).

Unfortunately, i cannot manage to have qgis declared in the command windows.
I have added "C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\" to the path variable. but it does not seem to be sufficient.

Would you have any tip on that ?

**EDIT**

As proposed by Andre Joost, declaring the \bin subdirectory is a first step.
Following [procedure](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/creating-high-resolution-images-using-qgis/), the command I am trying to run is:

```
 C:\...>qgis --project myproject.qgs --snapshot image.png 
 --width 1500 --height 1000 --extent 831421.30, 6496828.19, 860046.84, 6536520.86
```

QGIS loads the project and then the cursor freeze/standby. and Qgis answers no more for several minutes and I kill it. the snapshot image.png and companion world file are generated but are empty (7Ko png).

the cmd output is:

```
_path=C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Scripts
OSGEO4W home is C:\PROGRA~2\Quantum GIS Lisboa
```

**END of EDIT**

best regard,
Pascal

Comment: Add some more information, please. What is the actual command you were trying to execute, and what output did you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start qgis.bat, not qgis.exe. The bat is in the \bin subdirectory.

Otherwise the environment variables are not set properly.

If you want to start Qgis from a selfmade batch, you have to use a CALL statement to invoke qgis.bat.

---

**EDIT**

I'm afraid you are out of luck with --snapshot:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4076

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7079

It worked with earlier versions of QGIS (when the blog was actually written). I get the same behaviour with Lisboa and Master from last November.

Comment: thanks; adding the QGIS \bin subdirectory made it available for the cmd.