# Opening folder using QGIS action with Total Commander

Tags: qgis, actions

Is it possible to open a folder, with QGIS' "run feature action", using Total Commander instead of explorer?

Something like:

explorer [%'C:\myfolder'%]

needs to be

C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD.EXE [%'C:\myfolder'%]

Comment: Actually I need to open a folder witch contains some picture related to a point feature shape file, so with the info button I open the action menu to be redirected from Qgis to the exact folder and I can see what photos are related to the selected point. Furthermore the folder's path to be opened is stored as a point's attribute

Comment: What is wrong now? I believe it is more a TotalCommander question (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482126/how-to-open-folder-with-an-already-running-total-commander-in-batch) for the required command line arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I tried that code before posting my question and it didn't worked, it resulted in a message "unable to execute command", even replacing the directories.

Comment: fyi on windows you  have to start qgis.bat, not qgis.exe. The bat is in the \bin subdirectory. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54778/how-to-use-qgis-from-command-line-on-windows

Comment: qgis.bat opens the 3.14 version instead of the 3.10 long term release, but same message appears:unable to execute command

@echo off
SET totalc="C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE"
set folder="C:\ "
ECHO opening %folder% with %totalc%
%totalc% %folder%
ECHO opened

Comment: So there is no easy way to replace the file manager which opens a path? I mean just changing the word "explorer" with some code that says: "open this folder (reading its path from the attribute table) using Total Commander instead of windows' file manager"

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I had in mind but it works.
Save this batch file (similar to the one found in the link suggested above by JGH):

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set "totalc=C:\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE"
    set "folder=%1"
    echo opening "%folder%" with "%totalc%"
    "%totalc%" /O /T /L="%folder%"
    echo opened
```

Call the batch file inside QGIS using this Windows action:

```
C:/Users/BATCHFILEPATH.bat [%PATH%]
```

where [%PATH%] is the field that stores the folder to be opened.